# EF Custom Result Set Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, objectcontext

I am wondering if there is a way, using Entity Framework, of mapping results from arbitrary sql, like [ResultSetMapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) in Doctrine. I know i can create a configuration class doing the mapping but that requires me registering the class as an entity type.
What i am trying to do is utilize the materialization element (Object Services) of EF without the rest of EF. Sometimes i have results from a proc with cryptic or less meaningful column names, but need to map to classes with more meaningful property names but have no permission to alter the proc definition, e.g:

```sql
exec dbo.getRecDetail @var
```

returning columns :

```
sd, ed, nm, ....
```

which should be mapped to a class such as:

```cs
  class Obj{
       public DateTime StartDate; //sd
       public DateTime EndDate; //ed
       public String Name; //nm
       ....
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .EDMX file (designer) with database first approach you can import your stored procedures into the model (simply select stored procedures in wizard) and [map their results to complex types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456824%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

It actually works with arbitrary SQL queries as well but those queries cannot be imported into the model automatically (because they don't exist in your database). It requires manual modification of storage model in EDMX file (it is XML - check documentation for [`Function` and `CommandText` elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj652016)). Once you do that you cannot use update from database feature of the designer any more because it would delete your custom queries.

If you are using code first there is currently no option to map results of stored procedures or custom queries. You can only use automatic mapping which requires your class to have properties with exactly same name as columns in result sets.

Comment: Thank you Ladislav, i try to avoid working with the EDMX file, i was doing code first and according to my thinking i thought a library such as EF should have the option to pass some mapping meta.
I guess for now i have to make do with complex types as you suggested. Thnx very much